# Web Development -- Not Having to Clear your Cache Each Time

Tags: firefox, caching, google-chrome

Working with sensitive files that require the cache to be cleared each time... how do I tell Firefox and Chrome to clear my cache each time I refresh the page and/or not cache to begin with?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In firefox type about:config in your address bar and set 'network.http.use-cache' to false.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, there is an Add-on called 'Web Developer'. Among many useful features, it has a 'Disable Cache' option that's easy to toggle on and off.

Answer (score 1):

you could also set HTTP headers (or used the in-page `<meta http-equiv=` equivalents, for HTML) to disallow caching of those files.

Answer (score 1):

Also, reloading the page with Cmd-Shft-R (sorry, that's for Mac, I guess it's Ctrl-Shft-R for Windows) seems to avoid using the cache.

Comment: Using this for now. IS there anyway to turn off cache permanent like? ;)

Comment: You mean from the server? If your data is sensitive the server should tell the client not to cache the data. You control this by sending Cache-Control and Expires headers from your server. Maybe also consider using HTTPS.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me.